# If $f(x)=\sum_{0}^{\infty}b_n(x-5)^n$ for all $x$, write a formula for $b_8$.

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

If $f(x)=\sum_{0}^{\infty}b_n(x-5)^n$ for all $x$, write a formula for $b_8$.

Now I know that $b_n=\dfrac{f^{(n)}(5)}{n!}$. I have tried various things but I think there is something wrong with my understanding of Taylor series or something. I don't seem to understand what $f$ will be here. And how do I find 8th derivative of $f$?

Please help. An answer will help clear my doubts and make my understanding better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, we are given a general function and our interest would be to find its corresponding Taylor series or taylor polynomial, perhaps as an approximation function.

In this case, you are give the Taylor expansion itself. So given a general $f$ with a Taylor expansion, what would the corresponding coefficient be? Well done.
$$b_8=\frac{f^{(8)}(5)}{8!}.$$

When you are given a specific $f$, you can then evaluate the coefficient using that formula.